# Send large amount of data from client to server

Tags: xml, ajax, client-server, client-side, data-transfer

In my project I have a huge form with parameters more than 50. I have managed to show them in a nicer way to the client.

All parameters should be stored and I need to store history of each edit as well. I thought to store the values in an XML file temporary and  send it the the serve at last. I had a deadlock on that as we can not create XML with client side scripting.

I tried to put all those values to the variables and send to the server with AJAX (POST/GET). It works perfectly. But I feel this is not a good practise, so there should be a proper way to do that.

The problem is how could I able to pass those values to the server in an efficient way?

Can anyone help me out this?